# Execute more JS after other is completley finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

**Case:**
I have a web form that gets submitted via:

```
 $('#myForm').on('valid', function (e) { ... }
```

Inside that function I start with a code part to get a geo location from an address.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = $('#address').val();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $('#latlng').val(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
});
```

See that I add the geo location inside a hidden input field.

After that part, I call `$.ajax({ ... })` to send the data.

**The problem:**
The ajax call sends the data before the hidden field is filled with the geo location (that one is still running; with success).

**Question**
How can I make sure the `$.ajax` call is activated when the code part before it is ended?

Do I need to configure `$.ajax` with a specific setting? Is there a solution to wait?

Thanks!

Yes, I took a look at other answers, but could not the a callback (which was mentioned) to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the ajax call inside the callback.

Something like this:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    //this function is the callback
    //it will run when geocode completes
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $('#latlng').val(results[0].geometry.location);
    }

    //ajax here
    $.ajax(....)

});

//code down here will run before the callback executes
```

The second argument to geocode is a function, that runs when the geocode operation is completed, and after all the current code has executed.  So if you put the ajax call directly after the geocode call, it will always run before the geocode callback executes.

If you want code to execute after things that happen in the callback, you will have to call them from inside the callback, or have them wait on a message or event. You could trigger an event like that when the callback has completed, or (less efficiently) at a regular interval.

The key thing to understand though is that callbacks are asynchronous and will not run until (at the earliest) all of the code in the current context has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call should be within the `geocode` callback

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $('#latlng').val(results[0].geometry.location);
        //Ajax call here.
        $.ajax({});
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the JavaScript setTimeout() function and call setTimeout() AFTER the operation you want to complete First > Easy Peazy > And Yes Sabu would have coded it that way.

Comment: while you could use setTimeout, why should you when the api calls have callback functions. Not to mention, there are many variables (server load, internet connection) that could cause the response to take longer then the setTimeout is set for.

Comment: Agree with @PatrickEvans. Also, how much time should you give to the timeout?! Do you not see the issue with this?

Comment: @LeeTaylor exactly.  If the operation is slow for whatever reason (bad connection, big calculation) even a conservative timeout might not be enough, and then when its fast the operation will feel laggy.